# Where can I find jdo user custom generate value setting?

Tags: java, jdo

I'm maintaining a site jdo framework based.

There is a insert process and some column value is auto set by custom value (not sequence,uuid), but I cannot find any option to do that.

I googled it but no luck for me.

I was wondering if you could help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: You are using JDO so are using some JDO implementation (which?). And that implementation will have documentation. Internet search doesn't come down to luck, since there are ample pages of JDO docs out there